Firefox Security Error: Content at http://localhost:NNNN/ may not load data from blob:http://localhost:NNNN/... when assigning blob url of MediaSource
I currently have a setup to emulate Web Workers support when some functionalities are not supported on different browsers in order to use the same messaging system across all browsers. In this case Firefox does not support Media Source Extension in a Web Worker.
When in "no-worker" mode I create a MessageChannel and exchange messages between the "worker" thread and the main thread using the MessageChannel ports. This is how my code looks like overall:
// on port1 of the MessageChannel (representing the worker side)
postMessageToMain("createVideo")
const mediaSource = new MediaSource()
if (workerSupported){
  const handle = mediaSource.handle
  postMessageToMain("setSource", handle, [handle])
} else {
  const handle = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)
  postMessageToMain("setSource", handle)
}

// on port2 of the MessageChannel (representing the main thread)
onmessage(m){
  switch (m) {
    case "createVideo":{
        videoElement = document.createElement('video')
        videoElement.playsInline = true
        break
    }
    case "setSource":{
        if(workerSupported){
         videoElement.srcObject = m.data.handle // it is of type MediaSourceHandle
        } else {
         videoElement.src = m.data.handle // is of type string, here the error in the title is thrown
        }
    }
  }
}

This code works on Chrome in worker and non-worker mode while on safari, given that MSE in Web Worker is not supported, works only in non-worker mode.
I'm NOT setting any CSP header.
Am i doing something wrong? I found the same issue in SO but i struggle to find the actual problem and its solution
Minimal reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hxbktr?file=main.js
(open on firefox and check the console)

const mediaSource = new MediaSource() on Firefox is always executed on the main thread given that it is not supported on workers. That's why i create this messaging system as a fallback when some features are not supported in Web Workers.

I included it because it is the same code regardless if it is running in a worker or not. It's there just to distinguish between the two sides of the MessageChannel

On Firefox (which is where this bug happens) it always runs on the main thread. createObjectURL receives the instance of MediaSource

Then the MessageChannel should not matter at all. The cloning algorithm only sees a string, it doesn't know this string represents a blob URL, and for the  <video>'s src it doesn't matter that it went through the MessageChannel's cloning. So you can certainly reduce your problem on videoElement.src = new MediaSource(), it's very unlikely that your setup with the fake worker is responsible.

It's what i thought as well, but i tried other mse demos on firefox and they worked fine so i thought the only different variable is this message system in place. Given that the code is really simple, i can't wrap my head around the real cause of this issue, it really looks like a bug in Firefox

Might be, moreover since you say it works in other browsers, but once again, I truly doubt the MessageChannel has anything to do with it, so try to remove it. To find the cause of an issue it's best to remove anything that's unrelated, until you find the bare minimum to replicate the issue. When you have only one or two variables that cause the issue it's generally obvious what's causing it, if it's not, we're here to help. But you need to produce this [mcve]. Now, remember to also deactivate all the browser plugins you could have.

Sorry for the delay, after hours and hours of debugging i managed to find the culprit in the MessageChannel. Here's a minimal repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hxbktr?file=main.js
Opening this demo on firefox gives the security error

Very weird bug where it seems they don't hold the link between the MediaSource and the blob: URL when this latter isn't consumed in the same task it was created. Here is an actual minimal example:


const video = document.querySelector('video');
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
setTimeout(() => {
  video.src = url;
});
<video controls></video>



Setting the src synchronously would avoid the bug


const video = document.querySelector('video');
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
video.src = url;
<video controls></video>



and so would creating the blob: URL from the async callback:


const video = document.querySelector('video');
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
setTimeout(() => {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
});
<video controls></video>



So for your case you may want to mock the Worker context with synchronous operations instead:
// assuming you don't use addEventListener()
const fakeMain = { postMessage(data) { fakeWorker.onmessage?.({ data }); } };
const fakeWorker = { postMessage(data) { fakeMain.onmessage?.({ data }); } };



/*
Copyright 2017 Google Inc.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

'use strict';

// This code adapted from Eric Bidelman's demo at
// http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html

var FILE = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm';
var NUM_CHUNKS = 5;
var video = document.querySelector('video');

if (!window.MediaSource) {
  alert('The MediaSource API is not available on this platform');
}

const fakeMain = { postMessage(data) { fakeWorker.onmessage?.({ data }); } };
const fakeWorker = { postMessage(data) { fakeMain.onmessage?.({ data }); } };

fakeWorker.onmessage = (message) => {
  console.log('received message', message);
  switch (message.data.type) {
    case 'init': {
      console.log('received message in worker');
      const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
      mediaSource.addEventListener(
        'sourceopen',
        function () {
          var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(
            'video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"'
          );
          console.log(sourceBuffer);

          log('MediaSource readyState: ' + this.readyState);

          get(FILE, function (uInt8Array) {
            var file = new Blob([uInt8Array], {
              type: 'video/webm',
            });
            var chunkSize = Math.ceil(file.size / NUM_CHUNKS);

            log('Number of chunks: ' + NUM_CHUNKS);
            log('Chunk size: ' + chunkSize + ', total size: ' + file.size);

            // Slice the video into NUM_CHUNKS and append each to the media element.
            var i = 0;

            (function readChunk_(i) {
              // eslint-disable-line no-shadow
              var reader = new FileReader();

              // Reads aren't guaranteed to finish in the same order they're started in,
              // so we need to read + append the next chunk after the previous reader
              // is done (onload is fired).
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));
                log('Appending chunk: ' + i);
                if (i === NUM_CHUNKS - 1) {
                  sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function () {
                    if (
                      !sourceBuffer.updating &&
                      mediaSource.readyState === 'open'
                    ) {
                      mediaSource.endOfStream();
                    }
                  });
                } else {
                  if (video.paused) {
                    video.play(); // Start playing after 1st chunk is appended.
                  }
                  readChunk_(++i);
                }
              };

              var startByte = chunkSize * i;
              var chunk = file.slice(startByte, startByte + chunkSize);

              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
            })(i); // Start the recursive call by self calling.
          });
        },
        false
      );

      mediaSource.addEventListener(
        'sourceended',
        function () {
          log('MediaSource readyState: ' + this.readyState);
        },
        false
      );
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
      fakeWorker.postMessage({ type: 'setSrc', url });
    }
  }
};

fakeMain.onmessage = (message) => {
  switch (message.data.type) {
    case 'setSrc': {
      console.log('received message in main');

      video.src = message.data.url;
    }
  }
};

document.querySelector('[data-num-chunks]').textContent = NUM_CHUNKS;
fakeMain.postMessage({ type: 'init' });
function get(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) {
      alert('Unexpected status code ' + xhr.status + ' for ' + url);
      return false;
    }
    callback(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
  };
}

function log(message) {
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += message + '<br /><br />';
}
<video controls></video>
<div data-num-chunks></div>
<div id="data"></div>



I see you did open https://bugzil.la/1906040 Let's hope this gets some traction and gets fixed soon enough.
